# How to convert Datetime according to timezone selected from combobox in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have listed all timezone available in the system in a combobox. I have to change datetime according to the timezone selected. Will u help me to solve this problem?

Comment: be more specific, post some code snippet

Comment: What format are your time zone identifiers in? What kind of DateTime do you have? Please give much more context... see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

did you googled your question first ?

```
public static DateTime ConvertTime(
DateTime dateTime,
TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone,
TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone
)
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx